# пропорциональное уменьшение квадрата

Tags: css, css3

добрых времени суток, появилась задача пропорционально уменьшить квадрат, размерами  50x50, не пойму как это можно сделать? (через `media` не вариант, т.к. будет куча брейкпоинтов), можно ли как-то через `transform: scale()`?

ставить `width` через `vw` и JS приравнивать высоту к ширине тоже не вариант.

заранее спасибо за подсказки!

```css
.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: а как вы тогда хотите, не используя vw и без media, и без js ?

Answer (score 0):

Например, можно это сделать при помощи абсолютного позиционирования и паддинга сверху (или снизу)

```css
.container {
  max-width: 50px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```